# How To Get Variations Product From Amazon seller-central API

Tags: amazon-s3, product-variations, amazonsellercentral

I am integrating Amazon for a store. In Amazon, every product has a default variation, but I couldn't find it in Amazon's documentation, has anyone experienced this process?

I read this document but i can't find it .
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/what-is-the-selling-partner-api.

i want get variation of every classificationid without ASIN number
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2EKt.png)

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever find solution?